# TFS release - which Windows user account is used?

Tags: windows, tfs, permissions

When I perform a TFS release, one of the steps that happens is copying my web app's DLL's from a staging location to the wwwroot folder.

When TFS does the file copy, is there any way to tell which Windows account it is running under? Is it possible to configure this to be a different account?

I am guessing the user is just the I_USR account on the machine that hosts the TFS web site (where I click the button to release).

We need to know the user name because we need to ask our IT team to grant folder permissions for that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the plain old "Copy" task, it's using whatever account the agent service is running as.

If you need to use a specific account, then use the Windows Machine File Copy task, which allows you to specify credentials.